# sum in empty row

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've table like this, each product_id separated by dot

```
------------------------  
| product_id |  price  |  
------------------------  
| 1          |         |   
| 1.2        |         |  
| 1.2.1      |  1      |  
| 1.2.2      |  2      |  
| 1.2.3      |  1      |  
| 1.3        |         |  
| 1.3.1      |  1      |  
| 1.3.2      |  1      |
```

i need to count (sum) each product_id so I can see each head of product_id (smaller of product_id number), here is the result that I want

```
------------------------  
| product_id |  price  |  
------------------------  
| 1          |  6      |  
| 1.2        |  4      |  
| 1.2.1      |  1      |  
| 1.2.2      |  2      |  
| 1.2.3      |  1      |  
| 1.3        |  2      |  
| 1.3.1      |  1      |  
| 1.3.2      |  1      |
```

what sql statement that should I use..?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? What's the column types of your table? What is your "rule" according to which you want to populate the price field? You're really not *asking a question*.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Is that really so? Perhaps you should peruse my answer below, and be more cautious in your broad generalizations on the capability of SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sql:

```
SELECT  parent.product_id, sum(child.price) as price
FROM Table1 AS parent left join Table1 AS child
     on child.product_id like parent.product_id & "*"
group by parent.product_id

union

select product_id, price
from table1
where price is not null

order by product_id
;
```

generates the reqired output for your sample data.

Note a few things that are useful in building SQL queries:

- The use of UNION to compose two separate pieces of the result set.
- The use of GROUP BY to generate the subtotals.
- That the use of LIKE in the JOIN clause will cause performance problems on large data sets. This can be alleviated by creating a permanent mapping table from the detailed *product_id* values to the sub-total hierarchy; in essence, remove the subtotal product_id rows from the price table.